# Tooltip mouse move issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used tool tip on mouse move. its working fine. but I couldn't access inside the anchor tag element. mouse cursor shouldn't be moved inside the tool tip container. I don't use any plugin for tool tip.  can anyone solve the issue.

```
$(document).on('mousemove','.showmobileRegfieldDef',function(e){
    var left = e.pageX - $(this).parent().offset().left - 70;
    var top = e.pageY - $(this).parent().offset().top + 300;
    $('#popup-content').css( {
        top: top,
        left: left
    } ); 
});
```

Comment: It will be easy if you provide relevant code.

Comment: Ah, providing code means inside the question body not in comment :)

Comment: **edit** your question and put this code inside. @MuthuduraiK

Answer (score 0):

```
 var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip span');
       window.onmousemove = function (e) {
       var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
        y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';
        for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
            tooltips[i].style.top = y;
            tooltips[i].style.left = x;
        }
    };
```

Not sure what you really meant from your question. Anyway try this js. It's working inside anchor tags too. :)

See this fiddle. Hope my answer helps. thanks http://jsfiddle.net/JVDFc/

Comment: I think it should be better to run the `onmousemove` event only if the user `hover` on the container element. Don't you think?

Comment: I want to cursor move inside the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to check the client position for a tooltip.
I would rather do this:

```
addTooltip: function(element, text) {
     var tooltip = $("<span>").css({
            position: "absolute",
            display: "none",
            background: "yellow"
        }).addClass("tooltip").text(text);
     $(element).append(tooltip);
     $(element).hover(function(){
         tooltip.css("display", "block"); 
     }, function(){
         tooltip.css("display", "none"); 
     });
},
```

The Code appends the Tooltip to the relevant Element and displays it if you hover over it. All you have to do now is change the CSS to your needs and you are done