# Tooltip mouse move issue in jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used tool tip on mouse move. tool tip it's showing but particular place not moving the tool tip. I don't use any plugin for tool tip. can anyone solve the issue.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.showmobileRegfieldDef',function(e){
    var left = e.pageX - $(this).parent().offset().left - 90;
    var top = e.pageY - $(this).parent().offset().top + 300;
    $('#popup-content').css({top: top,left: left});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tooltip mouse move issue in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645717/tooltip-mouse-move-issue-in-jquery)

Comment: That's code is not working

Comment: the question is the same

Comment: Do you have any demo? It will make other people knows the problem that you handling.